# Bash: Reading a CSV file and sorting column based on a condition

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I am trying read a CSV text file and print all entries of one column (sorted), based on a condition.

The input sample is as below:

```
Computer ID,User ID,M
Computer1,User3,5
Computer2,User5,8
computer3,User4,9
computer4,User10,3
computer5,User9,0
computer6,User1,11
```

The user-ID (2nd column) needs to be printed if the hours (third column) is greater than zero. However, the printed data should be sorted based on the user-id.

I  have written the following script:

```
while IFS=, read -r col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 || [[ -n $col1 ]]
do
    if [ $col3 -gt 0 ] 
    then
        echo "$col2" > login.txt
    fi
done < <(tail -n+2 user-list.txt)
```

The output of this script is:

```
User3
User5
User4
User10
User1
```

I am expecting the following output:

```
User1
User3
User4
User5
User10
```

Any help would be appreciated. TIA

Comment: What do you mean by sort the input? `login.txt` is what needs to be sorted.

Comment: Do those userID's actually match reality?  Are there only 9? If there are more than 9, are the names padded with `0`, e.g. User001, User002, ... User789  ... ?

Comment: @SaadUrRehman: in comments to the answers you've mentioned `user10` ... consider updating the question with a more detailed example of inputs and desired outputs

Comment: @markp-fuso thanks for pointing out. I have updated the question with a detailed example of current and desired outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your script (and I presume with the "sorting isn't working") is the place where you redirect (and may have tried to sort) - the following variant of your own script does the job:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=, read -r col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 || [[ -n $col1 ]]
do
    if [ $col3 -gt 0 ] 
    then
        echo "$col2"
    fi
done < <(tail -n+2 user-list.txt) | sort > login.txt
```

Edit 1:  Match new requirement

Sure we can fix the sorting;   `sort -k1.5,1.7n > login.txt`

Of course, that, too, will only work if your user IDs are all 4 alphas and n digits ...

Comment: This prints works but prints in the order `user1 user10 user2...`. Can we do anything about that?

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F, 'NR == 1 { next } $3 > 0 { match($2,/[[:digit:]]+/);map[$2]=substr($2,RSTART) } END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc";for (i in map) { print i } }' user-list.txt > login.txt
```

Set the field delimiter to commas with -F, Ignore the header with NR == 1 { next } Set the index of an array (map) to the user when the 3rd delimited field is greater than 0. The value is set the number part of the User field (found with the match function) In the end block, set the sort order to value, number, ascending and loop through the map array created.

Comment: thanks, it works but user10 is printed right after user1 and before user2.

Comment: Which brings us to the question I posed in the comments on your own question (which you hadn't answered) ...

Comment: I've modified the solution. Now adding the number portion of User as a value to the array.

Comment: Nice awk solution; one comment: you don't use `num` anywhere, no point in capturing it ...

Comment: @tink Duly noted and taken out. Thanks

Comment: `for` traverse order control with `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` is only in GNU awk.

Answer (score 1):

Sort ASCIIbetically:

```
tail -n +2 user-list.txt | perl -F',' -lane 'print if $F[2] > 0;' | sort -t, -k2,2 
computer6,User1,11
computer4,User10,3
Computer1,User3,5
computer3,User4,9
Computer2,User5,8
```

Or sort numerically by the user **number**:

```
tail -n +2 user-list.txt | perl -F',' -lane 'print if $F[2] > 0;' | sort -t, -k2,2V
computer6,User1,11
Computer1,User3,5
computer3,User4,9
Computer2,User5,8
computer4,User10,3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using awk for condition handling and `sort` for ordering:

```
$ awk -F, '                       # comma delimiter
FNR>1 && $3 {                     # skip header and accept only non-zero hours
    a[$2]++                       # count instances for duplicates
}
END {
    for(i in a)                   # all stored usernames
        for(j=1;j<=a[i];j++)      # remove this if there are no duplicates
            print i | "sort -V"   # send output to sort -V
}' file
```

Output:

```
User1
User3
User4
User5
User10
```

If there are no duplicated usernames, you can replace `a[$2]++` with just `a[$2]` and remove the latter `for`. Also, no real need for `sort` to be inside awk program, you could just as well pipe data from awk to `sort`, like:

```
$ awk -F, 'FNR>1&&$3{a[$2]++}END{for(i in a)print i}' file | sort -V
```

`FNR>1 && $3` skips the header and processes records where hours column is not null. If your data has records with negative hours and you only want positive hours, change it to `FNR>1 && $3>0`.

**Or** you could use `grep` with PCRE and`sort`:

```
$ grep -Po "(?<=,).*(?=,[1-9])" file | sort -V
```